# Explain that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $K > 0$ such that $ |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon \quad \text {as long as } x, y>K $

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Assume

$$
\begin{aligned}
&f(x) \rightarrow a \quad \text { for } x \rightarrow-\infty\\
&f(x) \rightarrow b \quad \text { for } x \rightarrow \infty
\end{aligned}
$$

for two real numbers $a$ og $b$.

a) Explain that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $K > 0$ such that $$
|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon \quad \text {as long as } x, y>K
$$

**My answer**

To be honest I'm not sure what the problem is asking. In the following I'm actually guessing.

$$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f(x)-f(y)+a-a| = |f(x)-a+a-f(y)| \le |f(x)-a| + |a-f(y)|$$

Q1: Is there some definitions and/or theorems I can look up?

b) Show that $f$ is a uniformly continuous.

I do not have a good grasp of uniform continuity. Where would you guess suggest me to start.

Comment: It may be useful to look up the $\epsilon$ definition of a limit.

Comment: @TheEmptyFunction Which one? I think actually there is more than one.

Comment: @EBO What is your point in context to my question? I do not hope this is rude, but I do not know what you mean.

Comment: @EBO I may be wrong but your function $f$ has an asymptote at $y=\pi/2$ so the values of $f(x)$ are accumulating at $y=\pi/2$ so it seems there must be such $K$.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I swear I saw an absolute value.

Comment: No problem...=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, it came from the following definition of limit

> $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x) = b$$ if and only if, 
>   $$\text{for every $\epsilon>0$, there exist a $K>0$ such that if $x>K$, then $\lvert f(x)-b\rvert<\epsilon$}$$

With this definition, you are on the right track.

Let $\epsilon>0$. From the definition of limit, there exist $K_b>0$ such that if $x>K_b$, then $\lvert f(x)-b\rvert<\dfrac\epsilon2$.

Then if $x, y>K_b$ we have
$$\left\lvert f(x)-f(y)\right\rvert=\left\lvert f(x)-b+b-f(y)\right\rvert\leq\left\lvert f(x)-b\right\rvert+\left\lvert b-f(y)\right\rvert < \frac\epsilon2 + \frac\epsilon2=\epsilon$$
$$\left\lvert f(x)-f(y)\right\rvert<\epsilon$$

A similar argument could be made with the limits to $-\infty$

From the definition of limit, there exist $K_a<0$ such that if $x<K_a$, then $\lvert f(x)-a\rvert<\dfrac\epsilon2$.

Then if $x, y<K_a$ we have
$$\left\lvert f(x)-f(y)\right\rvert=\left\lvert f(x)-a+a-f(y)\right\rvert\leq\left\lvert f(x)-a\right\rvert+\left\lvert a-f(y)\right\rvert < \frac\epsilon2 + \frac\epsilon2=\epsilon$$
$$\left\lvert f(x)-f(y)\right\rvert<\epsilon$$

---

For part b), first the function need to be continuous. We could easily create a monstruous function, nowhere continuous that respect the limit conditions.

If the function is continuous, let'a take $\epsilon>0$ and we are looking for $\delta>0$ such that if $\lvert x - y \rvert<\delta$ then $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert<\epsilon$.

From the first part, there exist $K_a<0$ and $K_b>0$ such that 
$$\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert<\epsilon \qquad \text{for all }x,y<K_a\tag{1}$$
$$\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert<\epsilon \qquad \text{for all }x,y>K_b\tag{2}$$
No mather the value of $\delta$ we have, the uniformly continuous definition will be satisfied for those parts.

It remains to show that the function is uniformly continuous on the closed interval $\left[K_a-1,K_b+1\right]$.

A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous. This is known as [Heine-Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem). If you are allow to use it, you are done. If not, look up the proof of the theorem and apply it to your case.

Since the function is uniformly continuous on $\left[K_a-1,K_b+1\right]$, there exist a $\delta<1$ such that for $x,y\in\left[K_a-1,K_b+1\right]$,
$$\lvert x - y \rvert<\delta \implies\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert<\epsilon\tag{3}$$ 
This is the $\delta$ we were looking for. If $\lvert x - y \rvert<\delta$, three cases are possible.

- $x,y < K_a$, then it follows from equation $(1)$;
- $x,y\in\left[K_a-1,K_b+1\right]$, then it follows from equation $(3)$;
- $x,y > K_b$, then it follows from equation $(2)$.

The function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Q1: For the to $-\infty$ I would replace K>0 with K < 0. Is this correct?
Q2: How can we conclude that $|f(x)-b| \epsilon/2$ ? Does this come from the two assumptions about the limits?
Q3: In the first part of the problem I can either use $f(x) \rightarrow a \quad \text { for } x \rightarrow-\infty$ or $f(x) \rightarrow b \quad \text { for } x \rightarrow \infty$. Right?
Q4: When I have to show that $f$ is uni. cont. Is it ok for me to use the theorem above? In the problem formulation it say $show$, does this mean by calculations?

Comment: @Xenusi I've updated my answer for some of your questions. You are correct with Q1 (see updated answer), but make sure to have different symbol for the positive and negative part since they are not the same. Q2:Yes it come for the definition of limit since $\frac\epsilon2$ is a number.Q3: We need both side to conclude.

Comment: @Xenusi Q4 is harder to answer since it depends on why you need it. When I was a university student, we could use any result that we had previously proven in class.

Comment: From where do you get "It remains to show that the function is uniformly continuous on the closed interval $[K_a-1,K_b+1]$"?